# How to write Regular Expression Object in BSON ByteArray?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mongodb, bson

How can I write `RegExp` Object in BSON format with AS3? What is the structure of it? How can I convert it to `ByteArray`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.net.registerClassAlias;

var reg : RegExp = new RegExp( /^hello\d+$/ );

trace( ( "hello2011" ).search(reg) );

var ba : ByteArray = new ByteArray();

registerClassAlias( "RegExp", RegExp );

ba.writeObject( reg );
```

For BSON serialization use BSON AS3 implementation from here: https://github.com/argoncloud/ActionBSON

Use static methods `public static function encode( document : Object ) : ByteArray` and `public static function decode( document : ByteArray ) : Object` from class `org.serialization.bson.BSON` to work with BSON data.